# ONE route on React APP is destroyed on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Ive been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why only ONE of my many routes in my react/express app is being destroyed on refresh. My frontend is 
React running on port 3000 (generated by create-react-app) and my backend is an Express app listening on port 4001.

I am using react-router-dom v4.2.2 with BrowserRouter to direct all my client routes and proxy from 3000 to 4001 when communicating with my express API. All routes work great and as intended except for one.

There is a link that directs to "/classroom/live/:classid/view" which on the click event works completely fine. However after navigating to that route and refreshing, the page is lost completely, sending me a 404 with a failed GET requests.

To be clear, I have seen a few posts on here that refer to this problem, but after reading all of them, the solutions for me were to no avail. I have tried the following methods:

1) Adding {historyFallbackAPI:true} to the webpack
2) Making sure the route is not matching any part of other routes

Again to make clear, all other routes work completely fine. That is what is so mind boggling to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

client package.json below:

```js
{
  "name": "wss",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "/auth/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/edit/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/courses/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/class/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/upload/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/files/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/post/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/user/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/preview/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4001",
      "secure": false
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.0.0",
    "@opentok/client": "^2.14.7",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
    "jbox": "^0.4.8",
    "konva": "^2.1.7",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.1",
    "medium-editor": "^5.23.3",
    "mocha": "^5.0.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^7.1.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-drag-and-drop": "^2.4.0",
    "react-drag-list": "^1.1.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-konva": "^1.7.9",
    "react-quill": "^1.2.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-scrollspy": "^3.3.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.79.1",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "mocha",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

index.js (Main entry point of react app below)

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from './reducers/index'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';


export const store = createStore(reducer,applyMiddleware(thunk))

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  ,document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js file below (All client routes)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Grid} from 'react-bootstrap'
import NavigationView from './Navigation/NavigationView'
import AccountView from './Account/AccountView'
import CourseBuildView from './Build/Course/CourseBuildView'
import CurrentCourseView from './CurrentCourse/CurrentCourseView'
import LearnView from './Learn/LearnView'
import LiveClassroomView from './LiveClassroom/LiveClassroomView'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getUser} from '../actions'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import LandingView from './Landing/LandingView'
import QuizBuildView from './Tools/Build/Quiz/QuizBuildView'


class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){this.props.getUser()}

  render() {
    const {currentUser} = this.props
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Grid>
          <Route exact path="/" render={()=>(<LandingView currentUser={currentUser}/>)}/>

          <Route path="/account" render={()=>(<div><NavigationView/><AccountView currentUser={currentUser}/></div>)}/>

          <Route path="/classroom/live/:classid/view" render={()=>(<LiveClassroomView/>)}/>
          {/*ROUTE ABOVE IS DESTROYED ON PAGE REFRESH ^^^^^ NO OTHER ROUTE IS*/}
          {/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */}
          {/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */}
          {/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */}

          <Route path="/teach" render={()=>(<div><NavigationView/></div>)}/>

          <Route path="/courses/:query" render={()=>(<div><NavigationView/></div>)}/>

          <Route exact path ="/build/course/:courseid/:courseinfoid" render={()=>(<CourseBuildView/>)}/>

          <Route exact path ="/build/course/:courseid/:userid/quiz/:toolid" render={()=>(<QuizBuildView/>)}/>

          <Route path = "/course/:userid/:courseid/view" render={()=>(<CurrentCourseView/>)}/>

          <Route path="/learn" render={()=>(<div><NavigationView/><LearnView/></div>)}/>

        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(initialState){
  return {
    currentUser: initialState.userReducers.currentUser
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{getUser})(App));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route was linked only part of a prefixed express route "class" and "classroom". This is turn was making calls to the API without my knowing. Fixed.

Comment: Apologies for the delay on response. Yes! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, can you please give more details what you have to fix this issue?? I'm also having the same issue like this